# onMouseMove + useState lag on custom carousel

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new at react and I'm having some trouble with useState renders with onMouseMove event.

I'm building a custom carousel as a training and I have the following code:

```
import { ReactNode, useState } from "react";

interface CarouselProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const Carousel = ({
  children,
}: CarouselProps): JSX.Element => {

  const [isMouseLocked, setIsMouseLocked] = useState(false);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(0);
  const [initialPosition, setInicialPosition] = useState(0);
  const [lastPosition, setLastPosition] = useState(0);

  function handleMouseDown(event: React.MouseEvent): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    setIsMouseLocked(true);
    setInicialPosition(event.clientX);
  }

  function handleMouseMove(event: React.MouseEvent): void {
    if (isMouseLocked) {
      const travelDistance = event.clientX - initialPosition;
      setPosition(travelDistance + lastPosition);
    }
  }

  function handleMouseUp(event: React.MouseEvent): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    setLastPosition(position);
    setIsMouseLocked(false);
  }

  return (
    <div
      className="carousel"
      onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
      onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
      onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
    >
      <div
        style={{ transform: `translateX(${position * 2}px)` }}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Carousel;
```

The interactions are working fine, the problem that I have is since I'm using useState with onMouseMove to track the position that's being used on the style translateX, the component renders a lot and causes lag. I tried using let instead of state, but then the componente doens't move at all. Is there a way to avoid a lot of renders or at least remove the lag on this situation, and still make the translateX update so the carousel move?